# Java - running another process using the exec() method

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, exec

I am having trouble running another Java process from within my Java code.
It's supposed to run in the background so there's no need for using streams or anything like that.

What I've tried is the standard method found almost anywhere:

```
private static Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
private static Process pr;
```

In my main method I call the exec() method like this:

```
pr = rt.exec("java -cp /home/luka/workspace/SocketServer SocketServer");
```

That throws a multitude of exceptions for some reason. The application in question is already compiled into .class files, of course.

I have also tried this, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479461/java-runtime-exec-woes-on-linux?rq=1):

```
pr = rt.exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "java -classpath /home/luka/workspace/SocketServer SocketServer" });
```

When I try executing the same command using the terminal, it works just fine.
I thought it could be a security thing, but I am not so sure because I can execute the aforementioned command without a need for "sudo".

Also, is this line of code needed or is destroying child processes done implicitly when the main process is closed?

```
pr.destroy();
```

I'm trying to run this on Linux using Eclipse.
I am sorry if this is a duplicate question but I've gone through most of similar questions but was unable to find a suitable solution.

Exceptions:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at src.MainWindow.connect(MainWindow.java:213) ~[JAVA_vj10/:na]
    at src.MainWindow.access$2(MainWindow.java:209) ~[JAVA_vj10/:na]
    at src.MainWindow$1.run(MainWindow.java:67) ~[JAVA_vj10/:na]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Output of

```
System.out.println(pr.getErrorStream().toString());
System.out.println(pr.getInputStream().toString());
```

is:

java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@4443ad
java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@1b74334

Comment: If you could post the exception, that would be great.

Comment: It doesn't look like that exception is related to the code you've posted.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I wouldn't know what it could be because there are no exceptions thrown when I try to run it from the terminal.

Comment: The stack trace tells you exactly where the exception happens. `src.MainWindow.connect` line 213.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Those exceptions are thrown in another method that needs this particular process to run but the process doesn't execute (I can easily see that there is no 'java' process in the system manager). So the initial problem remains.

Comment: If `rt.exec()` isn't throwing exceptions and your program depends on the `SocketServer` doing something, it's probably not doing it. Unless you show us, we can't tell.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis True, it doesn't throw exceptions but it also doesn't execute the process which breaks the rest of the code. As I've said, it doesn't show in the task manager as it should when I use the terminal - http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/834/5os5x.jpg

Comment: Do not call `pr.destroy();` that kills the asynchronous Server process.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well, this is weird. When I remove the pr.destroy() line the program crashes when I run it but it creates the process I need upon exiting caused by the crash. Assuming I understood the whole process.

Comment: My guess at this point is that the problem lies with the process initializing AFTER my program tries to interact with it. I'll try this with a delay of some sort after exec(), could help. It is becoming frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried calling this after exec() and it definitely helps although it looks stupid:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

I will try some lower values, of course.
The problem, I think, was that the process I needed initialized after my code tried to use it in the method from where the exceptions I provided were thrown from.
Crazy, if you ask me.

I intend on leaving this unanswered in the case someone else comes up with a better solution.

EDIT:

This method also seems to help destroying the process, also.
I've simply added a closing event on my main window where I call destroy() and sleep() immediately afterwards.